# how to mock generic repository in C# - Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm using C# and .NET6 in my project and this is my generic repository

`IBaseRepository<TEntity>`:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Add(List<TEntity> entities);
    TEntity Find(int Id);
    List<TEntity> FindAll();
    bool DoesExist(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Update(List<TEntity> entities);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(List<TEntity> entities);
}
```

and this is my `BaseRepository<TEntity>` class:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly BookContext _bookContext;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(BookContext bookContext)
    {
        _bookContext = bookContext;
        _dbSet = _bookContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Add(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _dbSet.AddRange(entities);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _dbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual bool DoesExist(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        => _dbSet.Any(filter);

    public virtual TEntity Find(int Id)
        => _dbSet.Find(Id);

    public virtual List<TEntity> FindAll()
        => _dbSet.ToList();

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _dbSet.UpdateRange(entities);
        _bookContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I need to add a repository for my project I add something like this - for example `IAdminRepository` (adding that methods which not existed in generic repo)

```
public interface IAdminRepository : IBaseRepository<Admin>
{
    Admin Find(string name);
    List<AdminListViewModel> GetAll();
}
```

and its implementation is `AdminRepository`:

```
public class AdminRepository : BaseRepository<Admin>, IAdminRepository
{
    private readonly BookContext _bookContext;

    public AdminRepository(BookContext bookContext) : base(bookContext)
    {
        _bookContext = bookContext;
    }

    public List<AdminListViewModel> GetAll()
    {
        var adminList = _bookContext.Admin;
        var result = adminList.Select(i => new AdminListViewModel
                                               {
                                                   FullName = i.Name + " " + i.Family,
                                                   UserName = i.UserName,
                                                   Email = i.Email,
                                               }) 
                              .AsNoTracking().ToList();

        return result;
   }
}
```

When I need to use this repository in my unit tests I use moq to mock this repository.

But the problem is here: this mocked repository cannot use `IBaseRepository` method - it cannot reach that method.

```
[Fact, Trait("Admin", "create")]
public void CreateAdmin_CheckForDuplicateNationalCode_ThrowDuplicateException()
{
    var admin = new AdminBuilder().Build();
    _adminRepository.Setup(i => i.DoesExist(i => i.NationalCode == admin.NationalCode)).Returns(true);

    void result() => _service.Create(admin.Name, admin.Family, admin.DateofBirth, admin.NationalCode,
                                     admin.UserName, admin.Email, admin.Password);

    var exception = Assert.Throws<DuplicateException>(result);
    exception.Message.Should().Be("Duplicate NationalCode");
}
```

The test will fail because the mocked repository cannot access the `DoesExist` method.

Mock verification is still working but in `Setup` I cannot do anything with generic repository methods.

I change `Startup` settings and try to use `As<>` method of Moq but it doesn't work.

Can somebody give me an idea to find out what the problem is?

Comment: You realize you have created a generic repository pattern to wrap an already existing generic repository pattern (EF), right?

Comment: There's EF in-memory provider, which can be used for unit testing. It is a lot more convenient and more "real" than mocking higher level interface.

Comment: `List<TEntity> FindAll();` will be "fun" when there millions of records in a table and you want one specific not identified by id. Laoding the db-table into memory and filter there.

Comment: I know that , Firo , its just a sample and Its Better to use AsNoTracking() to have a faster search  , in real project I prefer  to use View Model and use IQueryable Queries to fetch data from database

Comment: Its just an base structure and implementation to prevent duplicate code in repository , my question is : why mock doesn't use this I didn't  inject it  , I Inherited that abstraction , so what is the problem ??